# NEST - Atomically change an alias to point to another index

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Elasticsearch supports renaming an alias atomically, see [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html):

> Renaming an alias is a simple remove then add operation within the
>   same API. This operation is atomic, no need to worry about a short
>   period of time where the alias does not point to an index.

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_aliases' -d '
{
    "actions" : [
        { "remove" : { "index" : "test1", "alias" : "alias1" } },
        { "add" : { "index" : "test1", "alias" : "alias2" } }
    ]
}'
```

With [NEST](http://nest.azurewebsites.net), the same can be achieved via [Client.Rename](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/indices/aliases.html).

Turns out, it's also possible to atomically update an alias to point to a different index:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_aliases' -d '
{
    "actions" : [
        { "remove" : { "index" : "test1", "alias" : "alias1" } },
        { "add" : { "index" : "test2", "alias" : "alias1" } }
    ]
}'
```

Any way to do the latter directly in NEST?

Right now, I'm using `Client.RemoveAlias` followed by `Client.Alias` which is *not* atomic.

UPDATE: turns out, it's possible to do this by POSTing raw JSON via `client.Raw.IndicesUpdateAliasesPost`, but I still wonder if there's an easier way. If not, I'm planning to add this to NEST myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NEST client currently supports this functionality. Please use the `Client.Swap` method.

Comment: d'oh ... I was looking for something like "FlipAlias". Thanks!

Comment: @MartijnLaarman would it make sense to document this [here](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/indices/aliases.html)?

Comment: @Max Ahh i need some redirects i see on the new docs here: http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/indices/aliases.html . SwapAlias was removed in 1.0 but I'll be sure to add it back in. The alias() call in NEST 1.0 now allows you to what `IndicesUpdateAliasPost` used to but with a typed interface btw :)

Comment: @MartijnLaarman I don't see anything like a "Swap" command in the current docs.  Was this abandoned?

Comment: An atomic swap is now available in `Client.Indices.BulkAlias` https://stackoverflow.com/a/58295057/772086

Answer (score 2):

```
private void SwapAliases(IElasticClient client, string sourceIndexName, string destinationIndexName)
{
    var aliasNames = client.GetAliasesPointingToIndex(sourceIndexName).Select(a => a.Name);
    var bulkAliasDescriptor = new BulkAliasDescriptor();

    foreach (var aliasName in aliasNames)
    {
        // Remove the alias from the source index
        bulkAliasDescriptor.Remove(a => a.Index(sourceIndexName).Alias(aliasName));

        // Add the alias to the destination index
        bulkAliasDescriptor.Add(a => a.Index(destinationIndexName).Alias(aliasName));
    }

    // Execute the alias swap
    var response = client.Alias(bulkAliasDescriptor);
}
```