# Nest Client c# 7.0 for elastic search removing Aliases

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

So with the latest update with Elastic Search 6, The C# Client was also upgraded too. But i can't figure out how to write this code the new way with the new Client Nest 7. I just need to rewrite this code

```
            var indexExists = Client.IndexExists(CurrentAliasName).Exists;

        Client.Alias(aliases => {
            if (indexExists)
            {
                var oldIndices = Client.GetIndicesPointingToAlias(CurrentAliasName);
                var indexName = oldIndices.First().ToString();

                //remove alias from live index
                aliases.Remove(a => a.Alias(CurrentAliasName).Index("*"));
            }
            return aliases.Add(a => a.Alias(CurrentAliasName).Index(CurrentIndexName));
        });
```

Answer (score 6):

The APIs have been moved into API groupings

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();   
var CurrentAliasName = "alias_name";
var CurrentIndexName = "index_name";

var indexExists = client.Indices.Exists(CurrentAliasName).Exists;

client.Indices.BulkAlias(aliases =>
{
    if (indexExists)
    {
        var oldIndices = client.GetIndicesPointingToAlias(CurrentAliasName);
        var indexName = oldIndices.First().ToString();

        //remove alias from live index
        aliases.Remove(a => a.Alias(CurrentAliasName).Index("*"));
    }
    return aliases.Add(a => a.Alias(CurrentAliasName).Index(CurrentIndexName));
});
```

You can also reference [Nest.7xUpgradeAssistant](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST.7xUpgradeAssistant) package and keep using the same methods as in 6.x to help with the move to 7.x. You'll get compiler warnings with messages to indicate where the new API methods are located.